# Importing Typescript classes into React-scripts - is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-scripts

I have an existing app and I'm trying to import a Typescript file, I use Yarn and React-scripts.

> Module not found: Can't resolve './DiamondNodeModel'

```
import {DiamondNodeModel} from './DiamondNodeModel'
```

In DiamondNodeModel.ts

```
export class DiamondNodeModel extends NodeModel {
    constructor() {
        super("diamond");
        this.addPort(new DiamondPortModel("top"));
        this.addPort(new DiamondPortModel("left"));
        this.addPort(new DiamondPortModel("bottom"));
        this.addPort(new DiamondPortModel("right"));
    }
}
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something that allows importing TypeScript files.. but I'm not sure where to set that with React-scripts..

EDIT

Changing the extension finds it, but it still can't compile

> **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__DiamondNodeModel_ts**.DiamondNodeModel is not a constructor

Comment: Did you try with the extension `./DiamondNodeModel.ts` ?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention, that finds the file but it won't compile when added to component via this.diagramModel = new DiamondNodeModel()

Comment: Do I have to convert the whole app to use TypeScript to have a typescript component in my javascript app?

Comment: you need to configure typescript loader in your webpack configuration ... did you do that ?

Comment: Ahh thanks I thought it was something to do with that. I have no webpack configuration via react-scripts and don't really want to eject. Is that possible via react scripts?

Comment: Thanks that now seems to be generating jsx files under the typescript files. Is this correct?

Comment: Add this as an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1):

We managed to solve this problem by adding:

```
export { DiamondNodeModel }
```

at the end of the DiamondNodeModel.ts file.